# SQL/ASP Insert/Update data

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL database table with User info - ID, Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Email. I display this data for the logged-in user on a web page - so only one user data will be displayed at a time. User will be able to INSERT & UPDATE data.

I initially coded the page with Textboxes & used a dataset-SQLDataAdapter to communicate with SQL.

I spent a lot of time trying to get the Textboxes lined up etc. Although, the code is working, I am not sure if this this is the most efficient way.

May be use a data control? What is the best way to display & update the data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that SQLDataAdapater is geared towards working with multiple rows of data.  if you are only working with one row at a time, then I would probably stick with SQLCommand and create a **parameterized** query from your textBox values.  Example:

```
string queryString = 
    "INSERT INTO UserInfo Name, Address, City VALUES (@Name, @Address, @City)";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        queryString, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", tb_Name.Text));
    //add other params too
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Or a stored proc if he prefers.  Probably better that way.  Still using SQLCommand

Comment: Then use Dataview to bind the TextBox to the SQLDataSource? Or Is there any other way?

Comment: Abe Miessler, What is the advantage of using a store proc versus C# code? BTW I do have a SQLDatasource also setup as I was not sure what was a better approach.

Comment: Stored procs and C# code are two completely different things for two completely different tasks so I would not try to compare them.  You should be concerned with Inline SQL VS Stored Procedures.  Covering the pros and cons of both are beyond the scope of this question, but a good place to start researching would be reuse of execution plans and the separation of the business logic layer and the data layer.  Good luck!